# After deactivating NetworkManager, how do I add the DNS server address to resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I deactivated NetworkManager with `sudo apt-get remove network-manager` because I want to have all network configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

After system restart, I see that `cat /etc/resolv.conf` is empty.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

It seems the DNS Server address need to be configured manually. Is this the right conclusion?

How would I add the address of the DNS server to `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct. May I assume you are setting up static IP addresses? If so, declare your DNS nameservers like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

If you are using DHCP, the DHCP server should serve, in addition to the addresses, DNS nameservers.

Comment: Absolute correct. Everything is static. All my VM's should be servers and here I do not understand how DHCP can be used. A server should have all the time  same the IP address. Anyhow you comment confirms my conclusion.

Comment: I agree with you entirely but you'd be shocked how many questions I've answered where people struggle setting up a server with DHCP!!!